# Word search from 2D arrays using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code here. What I would like to do is access the 2D array and take out values like the words (STAR and REAL) from this array and store it inside the `newArray`. I only wish to read the words from left to right OR top to bottom.

```
let testArr = [
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", "S", "T", "A", "R", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", "E", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", "A", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", "L", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
];

let newArr = [];    //I want this to output ['STAR', 'REAL']

function scanArr() {
  const column = 15;

  for (let y = 0; y < 15; y += 1) {
    for (let x = 0; x < 15; x += 1) { 
      newArr.push(testArr[y][x])  //This code here does not work
    }
  }
}

scanArr();
```

Comment: What is your criteria for what is a "word"? Any horizontal or vertical sequence of two or more letters?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you consider a "word" to be any horizontal or vertical sequence of two or more letters, and assuming the "empty" grids slots contain spaces instead of empty strings you could take the below approach.

It does the following:

- For each row—

  - Join the row into a string
  - Collapse whitespace
  - Split the string on whitespace into an array of words
  - Remove words less than two letters in length
- Transpose the 2D array so columns are now rows
- Repeat the above for what used to be columns
- Combine results

```js
let testArr = [
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", "S", "T", "A", "R", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", "E", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", "A", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", "L", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
];

function findHorizontalWords(arr) {
  let words = [];
  arr.forEach(row => {
    words = words.concat(row.join('').replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').filter(word => word.length > 1))
  })
  return words
}

function transpose(arr) {
  return arr[0].map((_, colIndex) => arr.map(row => row[colIndex]))
}

let horizontalResults = findHorizontalWords(testArr)
let verticalResults = findHorizontalWords(transpose(testArr))
let results = horizontalResults.concat(verticalResults)

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it.  I tried to keep as much of your original code as possible, even though `const column = 15` is entirely unused, for example.

As you walk across each entry as you have done, add the letter to an accumulator.  When you encounter a space or the end of a line, flush the accumulator.  You can maintain two such accumulators, one for vertical words and one for horizontal words.

```js
let testArr = [
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", "S", "T", "A", "R", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", "E", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", "A", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", "L", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
];

let newArr = [];    //I want this to output ['STAR', 'REAL']

class Accumulator {
  constructor(output) {
    this.val = '';
    this.output = output;
  }

  add(c) {
    if (c !== ' ') {
      this.val += c;
    } else {
      this.flush();
    }
  }

  flush() {
    if (this.val.length > 0) {
      if (this.val.length > 1) {
        this.output.push(this.val);
      }
      this.val = '';
    }
  }
}

function scanArr() {
  const column = 15;

  let h = new Accumulator(newArr);
  let v = new Accumulator(newArr);

  for (let y = 0; y < 15; y += 1) {
    for (let x = 0; x < 15; x += 1) {
      h.add(testArr[y][x])
      v.add(testArr[x][y])
    }
    h.flush();
    v.flush();
  }
}

scanArr();
console.log(newArr)
```

**Notes**: I presume that words of length 1 are to be omitted.  Because your 2D array is square (same number of rows and columns), it makes the iteration easier in that you can just transpose the indices of the inputs.  But you could modify this for a rectangular array.  Also, you didn't really specify which order the words were to appear in the output array, but you could put vertical words into a separate buffer from horizontal words and concatenate them at the end, if that's what you prefer.